# Terraform and Google Cloud Functions: How to disable Unauthenticated Invocations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

I've been trying to replicate the creation a Google Cloud Function via Terraform.

As part of the security, I am trying to disable unauthenticated invocations as this is enabled by default in the GUI of creating a cloud task:

[image]

However, looking at the examples found at [the terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html). It does not seem to offer this as a option aside from authenticating with all users / a single user. But this does not seem to replicate the functionality of reaching the 403 page when clicking the link, rather, just creating a entry into IAM and Admin where the user is being assigned a role Cloud Function Invoker. My Terraform code is given below:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function-api" {
    name = "terraform-insert-group-members-api"
    runtime = "python37"
    timeout = 540
    trigger_http = true
    entry_point = "hello"
    source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.resource-storage.name
    source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.storage-object-code-api.name
  }
```

What do I need to include to achieve this? Or is this achievable for Terraform?

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this from the Google cloud documentation, and it looks like GCP do this as well.

You can control who can invoke the functions if you edit the permissions on the cloud function.

Basically following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) you can select your function (clicking on the check box) and remove from "cloud functions invoker" section the allUsers user in order to avoid the function to be public. This will limit who can access to your function. Then in the same screen you can ad a invoker so that the user can invoke the Cloud Function.

So it looks like terraform is doing this already at [this link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html) as Google documentation specifies it.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for sharing. This was the first thing that I attempted when following the Documentation, for a Single User and All Users. It does not seem to work as if you deploy a function and open the HTTP in a Incognito Tab, it will return a response and allow Postman requests.

Comment: Hello, 

I've tested this further, I created a function and erased the allUsers inside the invokators, and waited for around 5 minutes. This then gave me a 403, this was expected. It seems that it takes some time in order for changes to take place.

After this I gave permissions to a different user and used the next command to authenticate the user request:

curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"

The response was successful, could you try once again and wait some more time between tries?